# ALTER TRIGGER command in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, ddl

I have an existed trigger in a Postgres 9.3 database, which is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig
  AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON tab2
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc3();
```

I want to change the trigger to be:

```
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
```

[The manual on `ALTER TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertrigger.html) doesn't explain how to do it.

I want to change the trigger without dropping it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, it's not possible to alter a trigger in this way. an OR REPLACE clause does not exists for [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html). However this is rarely a problem because in postgresql DDL statements can be wrapped in a transaction.

```
BEGIN;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig on tab2;
CREATE TRIGGER trig
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON tab2
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc3();

COMMIT;
```

Comment: [`DROP TRIGGER` requires to specify the parent table.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptrigger.html)

Comment: Right you are @ErwinBrandstetter completely overlooked taht

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming version of PostgreSQL will support [`CREATE OR REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-createtrigger.html) syntax:

> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER will either create a new trigger, or replace an existing trigger
>
> **To replace the current definition of an existing trigger, use CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER, specifying the existing trigger's name and parent table. All other properties are replaced.**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON tab2
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc3();
```